# Cannot read property of value undefined in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am implementing display of zero value in the input box if the object is null however I am getting error Cannot read property of value undefined. So for the first time when the page loads the fedExTax property will be undefined. How to make it to return zero value to the control. The error points to the following assignment in the html [(ngModel)]="fedExTax.value"

component

```
 export interface FedExciseExpense  {

    coveragePolicyTypeId: number;
    is953D: number;
    value?: number;
}

private  _fedExTax;

  ngOnInit() {
    this._fedExTax = this.fedExTax.value = 0;
  }

  public get fedExTax(): BackendDto.FedExciseExpense {
    if (this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy !== 0) {
      return this.fedExciseExpensesInputs.find(x => x.coveragePolicyTypeId === this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy && x.is953D === this.currentSelected953D);
    }
    return this._fedExTax;
  }
```

html code

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-6 mb-3">
        <label class="col-form-label">{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.INCCAPTIVEEXPENSE.' + FedExciseKey|uppercase|translate}}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="fedExTax.value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
            name="{{FedExciseKey}}" numberFormat="numberPercent:.0-2" (ngModelChange)="change()" [required]="true" tooltip="{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.INCCAPTIVEEXPENSE.' + FedExciseKey + 'TOOLTIP'|uppercase|translate}}"
            placement="bottom">
          <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please remove the output syntax from ngModel if you think value can be null
**[(ngModel)]="fedExTax.value"** => **[ngModel]="fedExTax.value" (ngModelChange)="someFunc($event)"**

Comment: @AbineshDevadas The value being `null` is not the issue. `fedExTax` being **`undefined`** is the issue.

Comment: Can we see the `this.fedExTax` definition? Where does it come from?

Comment: The definition of the property is in the post itself. The get property

Comment: FYI.. the property is of the type FedExciseExpense  . Updated the post with the definition for FedExciseExpense

Answer (score 0):

Try by Assigning the Interface type:

```
private  _fedExTax: FedExciseExpense;
```

Comment: How do i return. If write the following it says number cannot be assignable to FedExiseExpense   public get fedExTax(): BackendDto.FedExciseExpense {
    if (this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy !== 0) {
      return this.fedExciseExpensesInputs.find(x => x.coveragePolicyTypeId === this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy && x.is953D === this.currentSelected953D);
    }
    return this._fedExTax.value;
  }

Comment: FYI.. the property is of the type FedExciseExpense  . Updated the post with the definition for FedExciseExpense

Comment: try by using this `private  _fedExTax: FedExciseExpense;`

Comment: How do i declare as well as initialize it with a value

Comment: I meant private _fedExTax: Array<BackendDto.FedExciseExpense>; and initializing the value field

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in the code anywhere you specified a value to

`fedExTax` ...

try to do

```
fedExTax = 
{
value : 0
};
```

before `ngonintit` .

Comment: How do I return the value via the property

Comment: This is my current property public get fedExTax(): BackendDto.FedExciseExpense {
    if (this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy !== 0) {
      return this.fedExciseExpensesInputs.find(x => x.coveragePolicyTypeId === this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy && x.is953D === this.currentSelected953D);
    }
   
  }

Comment: FYI.. the property is of the type FedExciseExpense  . Updated the post with the definition for FedExciseExpense